# Passing php session variables non standard way

Tags: php, forms

I use the following PHP code and HTML form to pass the "item_name" value to downloading page.

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['item_name']="item_name";
?>
...
<form action="download.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="133076">
<input type="submit" value="download">
</form>
```

I receive and use the "item_name" value on downloading page like this.

```
<?php
session_start();
$item_name=$_POST["item_name"];
?>
```

All this works fine, but I have the following problem that I hope to solve here. After initial click I want to come back to the same html page like this:

```
<form action="" method="post">
```

then do something using JavaScript, generate the link to "download.php" and after that be able to download the file. The problem is that by the time when I'm clicking the newly generated link to go to "download.php" the

```
$_SESSION['item_name']="item_name";
```

is already lost. So how I can preserve this Session variable to use it on download page?
Thanks.

Comment: it's kinda confusing! what do u want actually do?

Answer (score 0):

On your download.php page, you need to set the variable as a session variable:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['item_name'] = $_POST["item_name"];
?>
```

By doing the above, the variable will be stored in the PHP session and will be available wherever you call `session_start()`.

The way you have it right now is:

```
<?php
session_start();
$item_name = $_POST["item_name"];
?>
```

which will make the variable available only within your download.php page and nowhere else.

Comment: I'm passing and receiving the variable correctly. The code works. The problem arises when I try to do something on the page and then only receive variable on the downloading page.

Comment: @Ash Let me see if I get you correctly: (1) You have a form with hidden item `item_name`, (2) You post `item_name` to `download.php`, (3) You capture `item_name` in a session variable on same `download.php` page, (4)You are then redirected back to your original form?!

Comment: I want to have some time delay between downloads, so I'm starting the session but I'm not going immediately to the download page. Unfortunately during this time delay the session variables being lost

Comment: @Ash It's not very clear what you're trying to do. Perhaps you can clarify your question some more?!